# How use php "use" function in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In php I can use in my template:

```
use My\WebBundle\Classes\Util;
```

How can I put the same in Twig tempate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create objects in twig template, but you can pass them in twig template from controller:

```
public function postsAction() {

    return $this->render('AcmeBlogBundle:User:posts.html.twig', array(
        'util' => new My\WebBundle\Classes\Util(),
    ));
}
```

And in twig template can use it:

```
{{ util.anyProperty }}
```

Comment: Hey Victor, is there anywhere I can read about that `use` command the OP is talking about? I can't seem to find it anywhere in the PHP docs?

Comment: Hey @JomarSevillejo , take a look at [PHP Namespaces in 120 Seconds](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/php-namespaces-in-120-seconds) free course by KnpUniversity - there will be an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want PHP in your twig template. All you need to do is tell twig what variables you use. It's part of the MVC.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller